# People Search and User Profiles SP 2016

Tags: jquery, csom, 2016, user-profile-service

Tell me why this [code](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25074.sharepoint-online-working-with-people-search-and-user-profiles.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) does not work in SharePoint server 2016 on-premises, but is working 2013? Possible problem in another `sourceId("B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31")`???

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/15/sp.UserProfiles.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSearch").click(function () {
            users = [];
            userProfileProperties = [];
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getAllUsers);
        });
    });

    var users = [];
    var userProfileProperties = [];

    //Method to fetch all the users
    function getAllUsers() {

        //Textbox value containing search term
        var searchTerm = $("#txtSearchBox").val();
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        //Building Keyword query for the search
        var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(clientContext);
        keywordQuery.set_queryText(searchTerm);
        keywordQuery.set_sourceId("B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31");
        keywordQuery.set_rowLimit(500);
        keywordQuery.set_trimDuplicates(false);
        var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(clientContext);
        results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryError);

    }
    function onQueryError(sender, args) {
        alert(args.get_message());
    }
    function onQuerySuccess() {

       $.each(results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows, function () {
            users.push(this.AccountName);

        });

        fetchProfilePropertiesForUsers();
    }

    function fetchProfilePropertiesForUsers() {
        var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
        var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName", "PictureURL", "AboutMe", "TechNetProfile", "AccountName"];

        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
            var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(clientContext, users[i], profilePropertyNames);
            userProfileProperties[i] = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
        }
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onQueryError);
    }

    function onSuccess() {
        var html = "<style type='text/css'> .floatL {float:left;margin:10px;} .floatR {padding-top:10px} .profile {padding:10px 10px;} .editProfile{margin-left:100px;}  div>img {height:72px;width:72px;} </style>";
        for (var i = 0; i < userProfileProperties.length; i++) {

           html += "<div class='profile'><div class='floatL'><img src='" + userProfileProperties[i][1] + "' href='#' /></div><div class='floatR'><h2><span>" + userProfileProperties[i][0] + "</span></h2><span>About Me : " + userProfileProperties[i][2] + "</span><br /><span>TechNet Profile : </span><a href='" + userProfileProperties[i][3] + "'>" + userProfileProperties[i][3] + "</a><br /></div></div><br />";

        }

        $("#divUserProfiles").html(html);
    }
</script>
<input type="text" id="txtSearchBox" /> <input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search Users" />

<div id="divUserProfiles"></div>
```

Comment: why are you using this -> keywordQuery.set_sourceId("B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31");?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *keywordQuery.set_sourceId(“result source id”)*: Sets the identifier (ID) of the result source to be used to run the query.
>
> Every result source has a different source ID in every site level result sources or in different environments.

You can create a result source or use the result source if already created at the location below:

```
https://siteurl/_layouts/15/manageresultsources.aspx?level=site
```

Click on the result source and you will get the `sourceid` parameter in the URL. Use this source id in `set_sourceId()` method.

**Reference**:

[Understanding result sources for search in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/understanding-result-sources-for-search).